# Capitalizing vowels, lower casing consonants

Tags: c, string

I have some code I have written which tries to capitalizes vowels and makes consonants lower case. However it only outputs everything as capital, i.e

> ABCDEsFGE

is the output from

> abcsdefge

```
int main(void)
{
    int a;
    printf("Non vowels in lower cap: ");

}


}

int vowerls (int f)
{
    f = getchar();
    f = ?  : putchar(tolower(cf));
    return c;

}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: There's no equality check here - it should be `c =( 'a' || 'e' || 'i' || 'o' || 'u') == c ?... `. You're just checking whether the bracketed expression resolves to `true` which it always does

Comment: the last condition  always evaluates to true.

Comment: Use if statement not conditional expression.

Comment: the variable 'a is never updated so this loop never ends

Comment: Also, since you're assuming input is always lowercase (you only test for lowercase vowels at least), there's no need to call `tolower` in the output!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
c = ( 'a' || 'e' || 'i' || 'o' || 'u') ? putchar(toupper(c)) : putchar(tolower(c));
```

is causing the problem. First, as @RichTolley said, you need to use `==` instead of `=`. Assuming you do that, what you would have is

```
c == ('a' || 'e' || 'i' || 'o' || 'u') : // etc.
```

Since parenthesis are first, it will start by evaluating the things in the parentheses and only after that will it compare with `c`. Since non-zero ints (and, by extension, chars) are truthy, it will see `'a'`, which it reads as 97, evaluate that as true, notice that there is an `||` after it, and stop evaluating, since true `||` anything is true. Therefore, it will always evaluate the first part of the ternary operator as true and print out a capital letter. What you need is

```
(c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u') : // etc.
```

This will actually check whether `c` is equal to one of those.

Comment: Thank you. If this fully answered the question, can you please mark it as the answer?

Answer (score 3):

The logical OR operator `||` returns `0` or `1` based on whether the operands evaluate to `0` or `1`. For operands like `'a'`, `'b'` etc, it's always considered as true value (`1`, non-zero). So, your check does not serve the purpose you're expecting it to do.

Quoting `C11` standard, chapter §6.5.14

> The `||` operator shall yield 1 if either of its operands compare unequal to 0; otherwise, it yields 0.

You can make use of a (fall-through) `switch` case to get the job done.

Answer (score 2):

With `('a' || 'e' || ...` you're not comparing those letters to `c`. You're just evaluating the logical `or` of the 5 letters, which will always be true. Try `(c == 'a' || c == 'e' || ...`

Answer (score 0):

Please indent code consistently, suggest 4 spaces after every opeing brace '{'
and un-indent before every closing brace '}'

Never use tabs for indenting because each wordprocessor/editor has the tab stops/tab width set differently

The 4 spaces is wide enough to be visible even with variable width fonts

In C, cannot do compound compares, need to make each compare separately

The main() function needs to be inputting the next char, so it can be passed to the isvowel() function
and check for the end of the input

'=' is assignment, '==' is comparison

sometimes, 'y' is a vowel,  the code does not handle that possibility

The returned value from isvowel() is not used, so changed to return void

When inputting from a terminal, the result will be interlaced characters on the screen
May want to save results into a buffer and printf() the buffer at the end

```
// prototype
void isvowel( int );

int main(void)
{
    int a;
    printf("Type letters; non-vowels will be printed lower case, vowels will be printed uppercase: ");

    while ( (a = getchar()) && (a != EOF) )
    {
        isvowel(tolower(a));
    }
    return 0;
}


void isvowel (int c)
{
    (c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u') ? putchar(toupper(c)) : putchar(tolower(c));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers have pointed out your mistake and how to do the comparison correctly.

Long chains of comparisons can become a bit unwieldy. You can alternatively check whether the current character is found in a certain string with the library function `strchr`, which makes the comparison more concise:

```
if (strchr("aeiou", c)) ...    // character is a lower-case vowel
```

You must include `<string.h>` for `strchr`.